# Dynamically creating elements and adding onclick event not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a for loop that creates `div`-elements with IDs like 'category1', 'category2' etc. The loop goes through a key/value array, which looks something like this:

```
"0" : "Java",
"1" : "JavaScript",
"2" : "HTML"
```

So, the IDs of the divs are 'category' + the key.

Within the for-loop where the elements are added to the `innerHTML` of a container-div, I add an `onclick`-event.

This is the for-loop that I'm talking about:

```
for (var key in categories) {
    categoriesBlock.innerHTML += '<div class="category" id="category' + key + '">' + categories[key] + '</div>';

    document.getElementById('category' + key).onclick = function() { showPostsForCategory(key, categories[key]); }
}
```

where `categories` is the above array.

The problem is, the `onclick` is only working for the LAST element in the array. If I check with the Safari-debugger and type "category3.onclick" it says null. If I type "category4.onclick" (which is the last one) it returns the correct function.

How is this possible? And how to solve it?

Comment: what does the rendered html in the debug tools look like?

Comment: Just normal divs as you would expect from the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with scoping. The click handler is pointing to the last value because that's what it ended up as when the loop ended. Here is a way to trap the value.

```
for (var key in categories) {        
    (function(){
      var _key = key;
      document.getElementById('category' + _key).onclick = function() { showPostsForCategory(_key, categories[_key]); }
    })();
}
```

Edit...

Also, string concatenation is not the ideal way to create html elements. In some browsers, there might be a delay between when you insert text, and when it becomes an actual html element.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.onclick = function(){...};
categoriesBlock.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: This isn't working. It gives just the same result: only the last one has an onclick event. Very strange. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Finally it works! I combined your initial answer (`_key` and the nested-function) with your edited answer. Now it works. It doesn't make very much sense, especially because I haven't really used JavaScript before. Anyway, thank you!